# Shibboleth protected Gerrit installation

Tags: gerrit, shibboleth

I'm attempting to setup a new Gerrit installation with auth.type HTTP.  Gerrit is deployed to Tomcat6 instance with apache frontend and accessible via ajp.  I have success using HTTP Basis auth

AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Gerrit Code Review"
  AuthBasicProvider file
  AuthUserFile /var/www/gerritpw
  Require valid-user

I would like to protect Gerrit using Shibboleth:

AuthType shibboleth
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
  Require valid-user

Error encountered when using Shibboleth:

The HTTP server did not provide the username in the Authorization header when it forwarded the request to Gerrit Code Review.

Is it possible to set the Authorization header in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use LDAP authentication and for Gerrit to be able to retrieve the user I added this after the Require valid-user:

```
Require valid-user
RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER %{REMOTE_USER}s
```

Hope that works for you as well.